# How can I serve robots.txt on an SPA using React with Firebase hosting?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, single-page-application, robots.txt, create-react-app

I have an SPA built using `create-react-app` and wish to have a robots.txt like this:

```
http://example.com/robots.txt
```

I see on [this page](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3023) that:

> You need to make sure your server is configured to catch any URL after it's configured to serve from a directory.

But for firebase hosting, I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add the following rules to the "rewrites" section in `firebase.json`

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/robots.txt",
        "destination": "/robots.txt"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
]
```

Answer (score 9):

In my `/public` directory, I created a `robots.txt`.

In my `/src` directory, I did the following:

I created `/src/index.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {TopApp} from './TopApp'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <TopApp/>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('react-render-root')
)

registerServiceWorker()
```

I created `/src/TopApp.js`:

```
import React from 'react'

import {
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom'

import {ComingSoon} from './ComingSoon'
import {App} from './App'

export class TopApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TopApp">
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/MyStuff' component={App}/>
          <Route exact path='/' component={ComingSoon}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Because path `/robots.txt` is not covered by the router paths provided, it took it from my public directory and robots file was published as desired.

The same could be done for `sitemap.xml`.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work for localhost, but not production hosting via firebase. Production renders a blank page