# How to serve robots.txt and sitemap.xml in firebase hosted create-react-app with react-router

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, create-react-app, firebase-hosting

I am trying to serve robots.txt and sitemap.xml at the root of my site like www.fakedomain.com/robots.txt. My setup described below seems to work at localhost, but not at hosted production. Hosted production returns a blank page.

Using firebase hosting, create-react-app, and react-router for url handling

Current setup mimics:
[How can I serve robots.txt on an SPA using React with Firebase hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239965/how-can-i-serve-robots-txt-on-an-spa-using-react-with-firebase-hosting)

**Folder Structure:**
`public/robots.txt`
`public/sitemap.xml`

**TopApp.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';

class TopApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    };

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<Redirect to={"/app"}/>)}/>
        <Route path={"/app"} component={() => <App />} />
      </Switch>
    )

  }

}

export default (TopApp);
```

**/src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import TopApp from './components/TopApp';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <TopApp/>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Firebase public directory, doesn't point to the `react-create-app` production `/build` directory.

You can try to change the [Firebase public configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#public) to:

```
"hosting": {
  "public": "build"
}
```

Or you can try start the process from scratch, but following my explanations and key steps of building and deploying `react-create-app` in Firebase:

1. Firstly, in order to have a public asset (robots.txt, sitemap.xml and etc.) in `react-create-app` you have to put the asset in your `/public` directory.

   Here's what [react-create-app' docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system) says:

   > If you put a file into the public folder, it will not be processed by Webpack. Instead it will be copied into the **build** folder untouched.
2. In order to build the app for production, you will execute `npm run build` or `yarn build`. This will build the app to the `/build` folder along with your robots.txt and sitemap.xml files.
3. Next step is to initialize Firebase with `firebase init` and to select *Firebase Hosting setup*.
4. **Here's the most significant part and where I think the problem is**. By default, the Firebase public directory is `/public`. But in our react-create-app case, our production files are located in `/build`. So you have to change it manually to `/build`.
5. Later Firebase will ask you if you want the app to be configured as a single-page app.

   1. Type **y** and press enter. *Accepting this option, later on you'll be able to use react-router-dom to navigate through your application*.
   2. It will say File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite?  Press
      **N** - because we already have it from react-create-app.
6. The last step is to deploy the project with `firebase deploy`.

---

Credits to the author of [How to deploy create react app to firebase](https://kaloraat.com/articles/how-to-deploy-create-react-app-to-firebase).

Comment: This is already my setup. I made sure by re-running this process, but it didn't change the result. I still see a blank page that has the index.html HTML code.